# In a Flash mobile site, where is the call to the database?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, database-connection, super

I have a Flash mobile site that I didn't create, but need to edit.  On clicking the submit button it checks that the login & password are in a SQL database.  The problem is, I can't find the method that runs a query on the database or where the database is even connected.  I've tried searching through the code for words like "SQL", "database", and "connection" without success.  I stepped through the code where I find a call to method "super", but then it goes back to the original method and then the user is logged in.  Can someone explain where the call to the database is?

Other things I'd like to know are:
Where is the SQL Connection?  In the main (non-mobile site), there is a web.config with a line that says

```
<add name="TPConnectionString1"
connectionString="DataSource=xxx.xx.xxx.xx,xxxx\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TP;Persist Security
Info=True;User ID=xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Where (what file: ex. web.config, xyz.as, etc.) would a similar line in the mobile code be?

What does super(type, bubbles, cancelable) do?

Here's the method for the submit button:
LoginView.mxml

```
        private function btnclicked():void{
            techController.username = txtUsername.text;
            techController.password = txtPassword.text;
            var evt:TechEvent = new TechEvent(TechEvent.LOGIN_USER);
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
```

Here's the TechEvent function that is called: TechEvent.as

```
    public function TechEvent(type: String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
```

Here's the dispatchEvent method: UIComponent.as

```
override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
{
    if (dispatchEventHook != null)
        dispatchEventHook(event, this);

    return super.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: On the web Flash apps don't access a database directly, they communicate w/a web server. However, Flash mobile and desktop AIR apps have the ability to use a SQLite database that is installed locally. Sounds like you need to determine if your mobile app is trying to communicate to the same web server that your non-mobile site uses, or if it's using the SQLite database.

Comment: To find out what happens when that submit button is clicked, search through your project for the constant `TechEvent.LOGIN_USER`. You've shown us the code that dispatches this event. Somewhere else, there is code that handles the event. For example you should find a line like this: `addEventListener(TechEvent.LOGIN_USER, functionThatHandlesTheEvent)` -- "functionThatHandlesTheEvent" is where you should look to see what happens next...